# Google cloud datastore + golang + embedded entities

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore, entities

I've been working on a package for API dev facilitation, that validates input data (according to a schema structure, mapping each field name to a value valdator/formator etc) ... I am sad to see that datastore does not want my payload=map[string]interface{} ...

I have then been playing a bit with the PropertyLoadSaver interface, constructing a slice of properties depending on a struct's values. All alues are pointers (which datastore does not accept excep struct), and I use it in order to not store the zero value for a non-provided value, but ignore it if the pointer is nil ... 
It works pretty well, the problem come when I want to use embedded structs with pointer fields ... I thought I would just add a property with a name, and a value of type "entity" ... This entity has a nil key, and properties (the inner fields) ...

I thought this would let me handle a json POST binded to a struct like

```
Type Outer struct {
  A *string
  B *int
  i *Inner
}
```

And

```
Type Inner struct {
  C *bool
  D *float64
}
```

... I would then fully use the power of nosql being schemaless and flexible, having entities that could have the optional property I or not, partially or totally filled (c and d could then also be optional) ...

This would be lighter, storing only the provided data and ignoring other properties (is the datastore GUI you can manually create entities of various forms) ... Retrieving lightweight struct with nil set to the pointers value while loading property if not set in the datastore entity retrieved from db, and thus not displaying to the user "bad" zero values, but not displaying at all what has not been provided and stored previously ...

In the gui of the datastore, manually creating an entity you can set a property of type "embedded entity" ... This is exactly what I am trying to do, but when adding a property to the property slice before saving (in the save method of the propertyloadsaver compatible struct)  of type "datastore.Entity" with nil key and propertylist matching the slice of properties of the inner struct ... I received this "invalid value for a property with name cinfo" ... ...

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you ever worked out the issue?